# Regular expression for negative values in flower brackets

Tags: java, regex

I need a regex for patterns like

```
1) {-1,}, 
2) {-1,-2},
3) {,-2}
```

Please help me out.

Comment: What is the pattern ??

Comment: I want to time travel.

Comment: What do you want to do?

Comment: @MarounMaroun ... to before I started reading this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this,

```
String regex="\\{-?(\\d+)?,-?(\\d+)?},?";

String str="{-2,}";

System.out.println(str.matches(regex));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
^\{(\-\d+)?,(\-\d+)?\}$
```

Hope it works for you.